# is there another way to create like 81 variables than writing them manually?

Tags: python

im working on a sudoku solver app as a practice, and i need to create a sudoku table of 9x9 cases.
asthey say: a programmer must find the simplest and fastest way to do it.

ok so here i imported the tkinter and numpy module, i created a numpy array called entries that will hold the 81 entry (or cases) of my table.

```
entries = numpy.array([])

def createEntries():
    for y in range(1,10):
       for x in range(1,10):
          eyx = Entry(window, width=4)
          eyx.grid(row=y, column=x)
          numpy.append(entries, eyx)
```

then i defined a function that holds 2 nested loops, one to loop as row and the 2nd to loop as columns inside the row, and a variable named eyx as example e11 or e35 whatever the case of my table is.
so lets suppose i have e11 ( we are talking about the 1st case ), e11 is an entry to the parrent window named "window" and of width = 4, placed it into a grid of row y=1 and column x=1, and then i tried to add it to the array "entries" but the problem is that it doesn't append.

i read a post that we cannot create variables using loops, so here is the question: if i can't create 81 var with loop, it makes it good practice to write them manually or is there another way ?

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted above, your variables don't need a unique name at each iteration. Why do you need to create another reference to your data. Here you could access e11 by simply doing:

```
entries[1][1]
```

after you have built the numpy array.

To properly append in your loop, do:

```
entries = numpy.append(entries, [eyx])
```

Comment: the problem is that the numpy.append() is not working

Comment: it doesnt append anything to my array

Comment: `append` is working fine; it just doesn't work like `list.append`. It returns a new array, rather than modifying the existing array in-place.

Comment: im using it as follow: numpy.append(myArrayName, variable)

Comment: The `numpy.append` function makes a copy of the `myArrayName` array, then appends the `variable` to this copy, then returns the copy with the `variable` appended. It does not [mutate](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/mutation.html) the original `myArrayName`, like `list.append` does.

Comment: is it a better practice to write these variables manually ?

Comment: @Pulse What chepner's saying is that you can't JUST call the `append` method, `numpy.append(entries, eyx)`, as in your original code. You have to call it and reassign to the variable, `entries = numpy.append(entries, [eyx])`, as in their answer.

Comment: You might be better off with an ordinary Python list here.  `numpy` is great for numeric arrays, but isn't actually giving you any benefit here.